# html forms are not showing in the template browsing

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-crispy-forms

[solved]

i am trying to make a blog in django and on the github [here is the code](https://github.com/ronyahammad/django-blog)

i am trying set the html crispy form template in change password option and made some file names password_change_form.html, password_change_done.html etc. but when try to browse http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/password_change/done/ or any kind of pages related to password change section it is not showing the crispy form. but login or signup links are showing in crispy form. password change forms are showing in basic django form. 
[image: this what i am getting]

i want to change it into the desired ones.

i made two apps : blogapp and accounts. i am copying the urls below:

blogapp/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (BlogappListView,
                    BlogappPostView,
                    BlogappCreateview,
                    BlogappUpdateView,
                    BlogappDeleteView,
                    )

urlpatterns = [
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete/',BlogappDeleteView.as_view(),name='post_delete'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/edit/',BlogappUpdateView.as_view(),name='post_edit'),
    path('post/new/', BlogappCreateview.as_view(),name='post_new'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/',BlogappPostView.as_view(),name='post_detail'),
    path('',BlogappListView.as_view(),name='home'),
]
```

accounts/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import SignUpView

urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/',SignUpView.as_view(),name='signup')
]
```

blog_project/urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/',include('accounts.urls')),
    path('accounts/',include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path ('',include('blogapp.urls')),
    path('',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'),name='home')
]
```

i pur password change forms htmls files under templates/registration folder. here is onehtml file for example:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Forgot Your Password?{% endblock title %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Forgot your password?</h1>
<p>Enter your email address below, and we'll email instructions for setting
a new one.</p>
<form method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form|crispy }}
<input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Send me instructions!">
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

this file is named as password_reset_form.html. there are are couple of othe files named password_change_done.html, password_reset_complete.html etc none of the password related files html are not showing ....all the urls are showing the basic django template.
i just can't figure out what am i missing and or what did i wrong? password change suppose to show the html form....not in django basic form.

please let me know where is my mistake.thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. I changed templates directory from blogapp to  project folder directory where manage.py exists. And everything else I did right. And it took a lot of time to figure out which is silly. Thanx any way... kept the answer if someone need this